# how to destroy a function in another function javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Function:**

```
function abc()
{
  $('#table_id tr td').removeClass('highlight'); 
  $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
  tableText($table_label,$table_id);
}

abc();


function  refresh() 
{            
  abc().hide; // Need help at this.
}

<button class="refresh" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

I'm trying to remove function/stop running `abc()` function, when refresh button  was clicked.

Comment: `abc()` isn't a loop or [`interval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), so I don't think you are actually trying to stop running the function. It seems like you want to *undo the changes made by the function*. Is that correct?

Comment: set `abc = function(){}` when you dont need abc to be called. Technically abc will be called, but since it has empty definition, nothing will work

Comment: hard to tell what is your expected result, to be honest, but destroying the function seems to be a bad approach

Comment: @sinaraheneba Yes, I  want to undo  changes. Can you please help?

Comment: Undoing the changes made by a function, removing the function itself (e.g., deleting it), and stopping a looping/repeating function from executing again are all separate tasks. You will need to make a function that undoes the changes made by `abc()`, or adjust `abc()` so that it undoes changes after they're not needed; or perhaps, depending on your app, it would be easiest to reload the content without running `abc()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, if `abc` is in the global scope:

```
window.abc = function() {
  return false;
}
```

or you could do: `window.abc = undefined` when it's in the global scope.

when it's a method: `delete obj.abc`

Comment: `delete window.abc` would be cleaner still.

Comment: I tried it in my browser to be sure.  :)  Maybe it only works because you use it on window.abc rather than just abc.

Comment: Yes i did indeed, but for you it worked? Mozilla Docs: "Functions which are part of an object (apart from the global scope) can be deleted with delete." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description)

Comment: Using Chrome.  [This](https://pastebin.com/Hu7uPYhB) is what I see.  Did you define it using var maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196960/discussion-between-nonickavailable-and-neil).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass param in your function and check condition like below.

```
function abc(arg) {
  if (arg) {
    $('#table_id tr td').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    tableText($table_label, $table_id);
  } else {
    //Do what ever you want if needed
  }
}

abc(true);

function refresh() {
  abc(false)
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants something like phps unset function. And why he should do this? He could write the else block directly into the refresh function

Comment: Nothing personal. Don't guess. Give option to OP , choice  what  ever want.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the code you only want to run once at the start inside `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('#table_id tr td').removeClass('highlight'); 
  $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
  tableText($table_label,$table_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function inside an object to delete it. You can use the window object or create a new one. Example:

```
const functions = new Object;
functions.abc = () => { /* do something */ };
functions.abc();
const refresh = () => {
  if ('abc' in functions){ functions.abc(); delete functions.abc; }
  else { /* will do nothing */ }
};
```

Solved :-)